# Customize the Cursor flow / direction on pressing enter in Excel worksheet / table grid using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cell, cursor-position, worksheet

I have a column as follows :

```
Column A---------------Column B
100 ----------------- 500
200 ----------------- 600
AA ----------------- ABCD
BB ----------------- DEFG
CC ----------------- FF
DD ----------------- GG
EE -----------------II
300 ----------------- 700
400 ----------------- 800
```

I want the Cursor to be present at cell location of "AA" at all times when worksheet is opened and when it reaches "DD", it should go to "ABCD" instead of going to cell 300.

This is a simplified version of a larger problem. I have several columns. I need a dynamic Visual Basic Code rather than hardcoing the same.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this  ?

Answer (score 0):

The hint is use worksheet events:

- Click **Ctrl+R** (Project Explorer) and click on the worksheet to show the worksheet code.
- Select the proper event (Activate or Selection_Change) in the right top combo box
- Put the code between Private sub .... End Sub inside the event
- Put the variable declaration alone before the event codes.

The code is shown below

```
Option Explicit
Const LBeg = 5  ' Line and column top left edit area
Const CBeg = 1
Const LEnd = 8  ' Line and column bottom right edit area
Const CEnd = 2
Public LCurr As Long
Public CCurr As Integer

' In every worksheet activation
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.EnableEvents = False
LCurr = LBeg   ' goes to top left cell
CCurr = CBeg
Cells(LBeg, CBeg).Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

' In every change of selection inside this worksheet
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False

'*****************************************************
' When current cell reach last edit line,
' goes to first line of edit area in the next column.
' When reach last column edit area resumes to
' first column in edit area
'*****************************************************

If LCurr = LEnd Then
  If CCurr < CEnd Then
    LCurr = LBeg
    CCurr = CCurr + 1
  Else
    LCurr = LBeg
    CCurr = CBeg
  End If
  Cells(LCurr, CCurr).Select
End If

LCurr = Target.Row
CCurr = Target.Column
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```